# Exception when using Rg.Plugins.Popup in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-popupwindow

I have a list view populated in popup.
I am using 1.0.4 version of

```
Rg.plugins.popup.
```

on selecting list item, I'm calling

```
PopupNavigation.PopAsync(true);
```

to close the popup.

but sometimes I'm getting below crash:

```
Android.Runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: Exception of type 'Android.Runtime.JavaProxyThrowable' was thrown. --- End of managed Android.Runtime.JavaProxyThrowable stack trace --- android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is not page in PopupStack at Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.PopAsync (System.Boolean animate) [0x0000c] in :0 at TCRMobile.ViewModels.TicketsListGenericViewModel.OpenTicketTabsPage (TCRMobile.DataObjects.Ticket selectedTicket, System.Int32 mobileID, System.Nullable`1[T] laborMiscTimeMobileID) [0x00000] in :0 at TCRMobile.ViewModels.TicketsListGenericViewModel+<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__0 () [0x00055] in :0 at TCRMobile.Droid.Services.DialogService+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__1 (System.Object sender, Android.Content.DialogClickEventArgs e) [0x0001d] in <5c6ae91b284846f5995b4e735df62b69>:0 at Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerImplementor.OnClick (Android.Content.IDialogInterface dialog, System.Int32 which) [0x00012] in <1ccf2ea9504d42c08b47c05ee0c5e9f7>:0 at Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_content_DialogInterface_I (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_dialog, System.Int32 which) [0x0000f] in <1ccf2ea9504d42c08b47c05ee0c5e9f7>:0 at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:d515a9d0-d793-4191-a5c6-5e450c1fd743 (intptr,intptr,intptr,int) at mono.android.content.DialogInterface_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method) at mono.android.content.DialogInterface_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(DialogInterface_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30) at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:175) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1534) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1424)
```

I assume crash is because some of my users double clicking the list item.
Do I need to always check the popup stack count before calling

```
popasync(true).
```

If updating the above popup library would solve this issue?

please explain the reason for crash and solution.

Thanks

Comment: Just use a bool Clicked; as a reference if user click, clicked = true and have a check if user has already check then just return;

Comment: Try to write before if(PopupNavigation.PopupStack?.Any())

Answer (score 0):

Try this Popup ViewPage.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="RootNamespace.Views.NeedHelpPopupView"
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:RootNamespace.Controls">
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation DurationIn="400" DurationOut="300" EasingIn="SinOut" EasingOut="SinIn" HasBackgroundAnimation="True" PositionIn="Center" PositionOut="Center" ScaleIn="1.2"  ScaleOut="0.8" />
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <StackLayout Padding="20,20,20,20" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Frame CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource YetiBlue}" HasShadow="False" Margin="20,0">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconNeedHelp}"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconClose}" x:Name="ImageClose" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
            <Frame CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource YetiBlue}" HasShadow="False"  Margin="10,130,10,0">
            </Frame>
            <Frame CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource White}" Margin="10,120,10,10" HasShadow="False">
                <Grid BackgroundColor="{StaticResource White}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Controls:Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding LabelNeedHelpTitle}" TextColor="{Binding Black}" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="20"/>
                    <BoxView Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="4" Color="{StaticResource YetiBlue}"/>
                    <Controls:Label Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding LabelDescription}" TextColor="{Binding Black}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="17" Margin="{StaticResource Margin10}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

This is the Navigation Part.

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            ImageClose.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Command = new Command(_ =>
                {
                    PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
                })
            });
        }
```

**Android**

In MainActivity.cs file.

```
Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, bundle);
```

**IOS**

In AppDelegate.cs file.

```
 Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
```

Try to this code.

And In Project **Rg.Plugins.Popup 1.1.4.158-pre** package is installed.

Comment: So updating this plugin and adding the above line in app delegate, does it close the popup fast or check to see itself if there are no popups in stack?

Comment: please change animation speed.

Comment: <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation DurationIn="400" DurationOut="300" EasingIn="SinOut" EasingOut="SinIn" HasBackgroundAnimation="True" PositionIn="Center" PositionOut="Center" ScaleIn="1.2"  ScaleOut="0.8" />
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>

Comment: my DurationIn and out are 100 @Limbani Akash

Answer (score 0):

Probably this would be no brainer solution.

Call it

```
await PopUpService.PopUpAll();
```

Service

```
public static class PopUpService
{
    public static async Task PopUpAll()
    {
        if (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack.Any())
        {
            await Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
        }
    }
}
```